# Get the count in the select in INSERT SELECT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql

I am currently having a problem in my query. I dont know why its not working. This is my query:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_leave_count (leave_count,leave_user_id,leave_id)
SELECT COUNT(*) as leaveCount, leave_user_id,leave_id
FROM tbl_leaverequest
WHERE leave_user_id=2 AND leave_id = 1
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE leave_count = leaveCount;
```

But when I replace the value of the update leave count to numeric, it works:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_leave_count (leave_count,leave_user_id,leave_id)
SELECT COUNT(*) as leaveCount, leave_user_id,leave_id
FROM tbl_leaverequest
WHERE leave_user_id=2 AND leave_id =1
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE leave_count=5;
```

I want to get the value from the select statement in my query [COUNT(*) as leaveCount]. How can I do it?

Comment: be carefull on using data type and its value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using a subquery here:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_leave_count (leave_count, leave_user_id, leave_id)
SELECT leaveCount, leave_user_id, leave_id
FROM
(
    SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_leaverequest
            WHERE leave_user_id = 2 AND leave_id = 1) AS leaveCount,
           leave_user_id,
           leave_id
    FROM tbl_leaverequest
    WHERE leave_user_id = 2 AND leave_id = 1
) t
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE leave_count = t.leaveCount;
```

I think your original `SELECT` has a problem, because `COUNT(*)` appears with non aggregate columns.  I got around this by using a subquery to find the count of `tbl_leaverequest` given the conditions in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Column name should be same

```
INSERT INTO tbl_leave_count (leave_count,leave_user_id,leave_id) 
(SELECT COUNT(*) as leave_count, leave_user_id,leave_id FROM tbl_leaverequest  WHERE leave_user_id=2 AND leave_id =1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE leave_count=5;
```